# How can I pass a tag in as a scss mixin argument?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I am creating a mixin to target a child element.
Example.
Targeting all `<a>` tags of the parent that has a parent of `section---blue`

I figure that I can pass the tag as an argument as follows
But I am not getting the desired result

**SCSS**

```
@mixin themeParent ($child) {
    &--blue $child {
        color: getColour("theme", "bluehighlight");
    }

    &--green $child {
        color: getColour("theme", "greenhighlight");
    }

    &--purple $child {
        color: getColour("theme", "purplehighlight");
    }
}

.section {
 @include themeParent(a);
}
```

I would have thought that this would compile to

```
.section--blue a {
color: blue;
```

}

Can someone please explain to me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@mixin themeParent ($child) {
    &--blue #{$child} {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

outputs: `.section--blue a { color: blue; }`

---

If you want more specificity, just add another `&`:

```
@mixin themeParent ($child) {
    &#{&}--blue #{$child} {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

outputs: `.section.section--blue a { color: blue; }`

---

If you want more scability, just iterate over colors you want:

```
@mixin themeParent ($child) {
  $colors: red, blue, green;
  @each $color in $colors {
    &#{&}--#{$color} #{$child} {
        color: $color;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `$child` in `#{$child}`.

```
@mixin themeParent ($child) {
    #{$child} {
        color: #000;
    }
}

.section {
    @include themeParent(a)
}
```

Output:

```
.section a {
  color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I put this in a simple way, there is no need to pass the tag as a parameter to the mixin function instead, u should pass the color of the  element.

```
<div className="section--blue">
                    <a>section blue</a>
</div>

<div className="section-green">
           <a>section green</a>        
</div>
```

mixin and css

```
@mixin themeParent ($color) {
   color:$color;
 }
.section{
    &--blue {
        a{
            @include themeParent(blue);
        }
    }
    --green{
        a{
            @include themeParent(green);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: thanks but I think that means the child always needs to be an <a> where as I want to change the child element